# How do I make my terminal quit on an empty cin input in c++?

Tags: c++, terminal, stdstring, is-empty

I can't find a way to make my terminal quit the program on an empty input. I have:

```
int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
    // Write your code here
    // Define variables

    set<string> words;  // The set
    bool more = true;     //  Flag indicating there are more lines to read

    // If there is no command line argument, use stdin to get the lines
    if (argc == 1){

        // Take lines in until a blank line is entered
        while (more) {

            // Get next line from stdin
            string input;
            cin >> input;

                // Quit if we hit a blank line
                if (input.empty() ) {
                    more = false;
                    break;
                }
```

I've tried:

```
if (!cin )
if (input == "")
if (input == "\n")
if (input == "" || "\n")
if (input.empty())
```

For each of these I expected the program to take no input, or simply hitting enter, as the end of taking in inputs and quit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`operator>>` skips leading whitespace, so it will never give you an empty string if the read is successful (which you are not checking for). You can break the stream with <kbd>Ctrl-C/Z</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-Break</kbd> (depending on platform) to put `cin` into an error state that makes statements like `if (cin >> input)` evaluate as false.

Answer (score 5):

Read line by line using `std::getline`. If the line is empty then the user just pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

With `>>` you need to enter some non-space characters before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Also note that your current input will only read a single space-delimited "word", not a line. To read a line you really need `std::getline`.

---

Example:

```
std::string input;

for (;;)
{
    // Try to read a whole line, and check if it's empty or not
    if (!std::getline(std::cin, input) || input.empty())
    {
        // There was an error reading, or there was an EOF,
        // or the line was empty (the user just pressed Enter)
        break;
    }

    // TODO: Do something with the input
}
```

Comment: It would be better to use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop with an `if (...) break;` inside of it, eg: `while (std::getline(std::cin, input) && !input.empty()) { ... }` If you need to differentiate between error vs EOF, you can check `cin`'s state after the `while` loop exits.